# How to install Ionic framework V5

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed Ionic framework with npm.

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

The installed version is 6.2.1, but in my work they using the version 5. How i can install the version 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6.2.1 is the version of the installed Ionic CLI. This is NOT the Ionic Framework version.

To check the Ionic Framework version of a project, open package.json and look for the version of `@ionic/angular`. It should be something like this: `"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.5"`.

Also, the versions of the `@ionic-native/*` plugins would be 5 or greater.

To sum it up, if you are about to contribute to an Ionic 5 project, installing the latest version of the Ionic CLI is enough. When setting up the project on your machine, running `npm install` should install all the required dependencies, including Ionic 5.